# Issue while creating spark datasets

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I am trying to read a json into a dataframe and then to a dataset.
I am facing the below issue. Could someone quickly help me.

There is a PrintDF dataframe was created successfully and below is the schema.

```
scala> personDF.printSchema();
root
|-- personDF: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- city: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- line1: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- postalCode: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- state: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- type1: string (nullable = true)
```

I created a case class to capture the above DF.

```
scala> case class address1(city:String,line1:String,postalCode:String,state:String,type1:String)
defined class address1
```

Below is the data that personDF has at the moment

```
scala> personzDF.show()

+--------------------+
|            personDF|
+--------------------+
|[CENTERPORT,5 PRO...|
|[HUNTINGTON,94 JA...|
|[RIVERHEAD,9 PATT...|
|[NORTHPORT,50 LIS...|
|[NORTHPORT,24 LAU...|
|[NORTHPORT,340 SC...|
|[GREENLAWN,166 BR...|
|[MELVILLE,1 MERID...|
+--------------------+
```

Finally while I am creating dataset, I am getting the below error.

```
scala> val ds = personDF.as[address1]
<console>:32: error: overloaded method value as with alternatives:
  (alias: Symbol)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (alias: String)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
does not take type parameters
       val ds = personDF.as[address1]
```

I did google search and could not find the reason.

Thanks,
Sivaram

Answer (score 0):

Actually personDF is an array of structType personDF, but it is not in the structure of what you are expecting from your printSchema():

|-- personDF: struct (nullable = true)

Are u trying to convert personzDF to address1 type? Then try like this:

```
val ds = personzDF.map(rec => rec.split(","))
  .map(rec => address1(rec(0), rec(1), rec(2), rec(3), rec(4)))
  .toDF()
```

Hope it helps.